# Minikube app can't be accessed on web browser with "<minikube ip>:<NodePort>"

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

On top of the title i want to mention that  `ping $(minikube ip)` is not responding (0 packets received)

I'm currently using docker as minikube driver.

Here is the full config and outputs:

frontend-pod.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: front-pod #pod name
  labels:
    component: web 
spec:
  containers:
    - name: front 
      image: my_dockerhub/xyz
      ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

frontend-node-port.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: front-node-port

spec:
  type: NodePort 
  ports:
    - port: 3050 
      targetPort: 3000 
      nodePort: 31515  # <minikube ip>:31515 can't be accessed on web browser 
     
  selector:
    component: web
```

`$ kubectl get service`

```
| NAME              | TYPE      | CLUSTER-IP      | EXTERNAL-IP | PORT(S)          | AGE  |
|-------------------|-----------|-----------------|-------------|------------------|------|
| front-node-port   | NodePort  | 10.99.154.150   | <none>      | 3050:31515/TCP   | 69m  |
| kubernetes        | ClusterIP | 10.96.0.1       | <none>      | 443/TCP          | 71m  |
```

`$kubectl get pod`

```
| NAME       | READY | STATUS  | RESTARTS | AGE  |
|------------|-------|---------|----------|------|
| front-pod  | 1/1   | Running | 0        | 66m  |
```

`$ minikube ip` --> 192.168.49.2

I also want to mention that the app is accessible on the web browser  only when i enter the url generated from `minikube service <service-name> --url` but not with this url: `http://192.168.49.2:31515`